# What does the term 'meta' mean?

Tags: league-of-legends

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is metagame?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7629/what-is-metagame)
>   [What is the Meta Game?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/58395/what-is-the-meta-game)

I've heard in pro player streams the term 'meta' SO many times, I would like to know what this term means Please if some one could awnser my question, I would be very thankful So please tell me, What does the term 'Meta' mean!?

Answer (score 0):

Meta is the current set style, per say. it is what is normally done. like ap mid, solo top, jungle, shields are becomeing more meta right now because of the lifesteal and spell vamp nerfs.

Answer (score 0):

It is the game within the game. It's using the best possible strategy that you can to win the game. You use number crunching and champion balance to win put a game in your favor. to put it the most simple way. :D

Answer (score 0):

Meta is a prefix that actually are involved in a lot of things. it pretty much means "about itself". "For example, metadata are data about data (who has produced them, when, what format the data are in and so on)" (from en.wikipedia.org/wiki/meta). so it pretty much means that the meta is HOW you play the game